# How to not open a console when starting program written in D

Tags: windows, user-interface, d, windows-console, ldc

I am writing an application in D. It's compiled with the ldc2 compiler, using dub configuration (target type: executable). The compiled program creates a console window, which I do not need since the application uses a GUI framework. I need a way to prevent creating the console window.

The only other example I know with similar behaviour is when compiling C/C++ programs with mingw64-gcc, which has an -mwindows flag. I do not know anything similar for D programs. Neither dub configuration nor ldc compiler flags seem to do what I want. Does anyone know what to do? Even another compiler could work, if it at least does what I want.

When the application is opened from CMD or PowerShell, no additional console is opened. The problem only occurs when I start the application from the Windows GUI.

dub.json:

```
{
    description (author etc.)
    "targetType": "executable",
    "platforms": [
        "windows"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
     ....
    },
    "versions" : [
     ....
    ],
    "libs" : [
     ....
    ],
    "dflags": [
        "-m32",
        "-static",
        "-release"
    ]
}
```

compile command:

```
dub run --compiler=ldc2.exe
```

**Solution**:

add linker flags as follows in dub.json

```
"lflags":[
   "-subsystem:windows",
   "-entry:mainCRTStartup"
]
```

this removes the console poping up at program start, if the program is not run from another console. it also enables the usual d main (void main() etc.), NO need for the winmain entry point. (that can be used if you simply leave the entry flag out)

Comment: In your dub configuration file, you can add an `"lflags":["/subsystem:windows"]` option which should do it. ... but I'm not sure that will work with ldc2, can you try it and let me know? The specific syntax might be slightly different, stack overflow suggests to me it might be `"-Wl,--subsystem,windows"` too.

Comment: did not work. i tried dub lflags[/sub..] and dflags -L=--subystem=windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

`"lflags": ["-Subsystem:Windows"]`

to your `dub.json` file to tell ldc to create a Window UI binary. The command line option to use is `ldc2 -L=-Subsystem:Windows`.

Comment: now when i compile my program, the linker fails with:
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)

Comment: the solution to that is apparently to add the winmain entry point, but as explained in http://forum.dlang.org/post/atzfdxpbpzzbidjdrjtg@forum.dlang.org , the d runtime is not initilialized then.

Comment: copying the code from the dlang win32 sample page (referenced in the dlang forum post), works. Also the d runtime apparently works here, so problem solved, somehow. not pretty, but that is what windows is....
thanks for the help! (your flag did the trick)

Comment: On 64 bit Windows with the MS linker the command line is: `-L/subsystem:windows -L/entry:mainCRTStartup` to use the D main without the console. Just translate that entry thing to ldc+dub's syntax and you got it.